# parse a JSON to an array jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to convert this object into array using jQuery

```
[["20"],["30"],["45"],["54"],["33"],["15"],["54"],["41"]]
```

I trying to get an array output like this:

```
[20,30,45,54,33,15,54,41]
```

How?

Comment: Note what you're provided appears to be a multi-dimensional array, which is nothing to do with JSON

Comment: This isn't even JSON. What you posted is a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: You can use jsonlint to help insure you have valid JSON

Comment: @kevinternet I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry it was a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Just use map() method to change each array of one string value element into a coresponding number :

```js
var input = [["20"],["30"],["45"],["54"],["33"],["15"],["54"],["41"]];
var result = input.map(x => Number(x[0]));
console.log(result);
```